# Windows 10 SSH "Cannot listen to port 3389"

Tags: windows, ssh, remote-desktop

I have Cygwin installed on a Windows 10 machine.

I am trying to use Remote Desktop from that machine, tunneled through SSH, to connect to a Windows 10 machine on a network at work which also has Linux machines.

I can SSH into my Linux box at work with port forwarding as follows:

```
ssh -l my_name external_static_ip_address -p linux_port_listen -L 3389:192.168.0.203:3389
```

So, SSH works fine and `hostname` shows the Linux box. However, I get this message:

> bind: Operation not permitted. Channel_setup_fwd_listner_tcpip: cannot listend on port: 3389. Could not request local forwarding.

Now, the exact same command works from Cygwin running on a Vista machine.

I tried disabling the firewall on my Windows 10 machine, but this did not help.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have already improved the grammar and formatting (this should show up soon), but please can you edit your question to be a bit clearer? Thanks.

Comment: Does the Windows 10 machine allow RDP connections (3389 is the port for RDP listener)? You can check via Start -> "Allow remote access to your computer" (type it in the search bar).

Answer (score 1):

The machine you are trying to ssh **from** has RDP (or something else) enable and already using local port 3389.  Choose a different local port number.

```
ssh -L 13389:192.168.0.203:3389
```

Then in the RDP client connect to `127.0.0.1:13389`.